# how i can to use variable into object name (sub object case)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose i have data like this

```
data = {
     personal : {
           sport : "Football"
     }
}
```

i try to extract string. it work

```
let str1 = "personal"
let str2 = "sport"
console.log(data[str1][str2])
```

The problem i have a more string. each string so different. how i can to use one for every string.

```
let str_1 = "personal.sport"
let str_2 = "personal.sport.xxx"
let str_3 = "personal.aaa.sport.xxx"
.....
..
let str_n = "bbb.ccc.ddd"


console.log(data[str_1])
console.log(data[str_2])
console.log(data[str_3])
....
... 
console.log(data[str_n])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I get what you mean but is this what you're after?

```js
var data = {
  personal: {
    sport: "Football"
  }
};

let str_1 = "personal.sport";
let str_2 = "personal.sport.xxx";
let str_3 = "personal.aaa.sport.xxx";

function getValue(path) {
  var obj = data;
  var props = path.split(".");
  
  for (const prop of props) {
    obj = obj[prop];
    
    if (!obj)
      return obj;
  }
  
  return obj;
}

console.log(getValue(str_1))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```js
let data = {
  personal: {
    sport: {
      xxx: "Football"
    },
    aaa: {
      sport: {
        xxx: "Football"
      }
    }
  }
};

let str_1 = "personal.sport";
let str_2 = "personal.sport.xxx";
let str_3 = "personal.aaa.sport.xxx";

function getVal(path, obj) {
  return path.split(/\./g).reduce((re, attr) => re[attr], obj);
}
console.log(getVal(str_1, data));
console.log(getVal(str_2, data));
console.log(getVal(str_3, data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Looping through keys.

```js
var data = {
  'foo': {
    'bar': 'xyz'
  },
  'one': {
    'two': 'three'
  },
  'error': 'Boom!'
};

var finder = function(data, findBy) {
  var keys = (findBy || '').split(/\./);
  var tmp = data;
  var key;
  while (keys.length) {
    key = keys.shift();
    if (tmp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      tmp = tmp[key];
      continue;
    }
    tmp = undefined;
    break;
  }
  return tmp;
};

console.log(finder(data, 'foo.bar'));
console.log(finder(data, 'error'));
console.log(finder(data, null));
console.log(finder(data, ''));
```

Option 2: using `Function`, many of developers won't agree with this, inculding `eval`

```js
var data = {
  'foo': {
    'bar': 'xyz'
  },
  'one': {
    'two': 'three'
  },
  'error': 'Boom!'
};

var finder = function(data, findBy) {
  var keys = '["' + (findBy || '').replace(/\./, '"]["') + '"]';
  var finderStr = 'return ' + JSON.stringify(data) + keys + ';';
  //console.log(finderStr);
  var func = new Function(finderStr);
  return func();
};

console.log(finder(data, 'foo.bar'));
console.log(finder(data, 'error'));
console.log(finder(data, null));
console.log(finder(data, ''));
```